# Push values to array in controller

Tags: angularjs

I have input fields on the DOM that I'm capturing using ng-model.

In my controller, I have an array:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
    // set an empty array
    self.manualEntry = [];

    /**
     * ensure form validation
     * @returns boolean - ng-disabled value
     */
    self.disableForm = function() {
        if (self.manualEntry.length <= 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
});
```

In my view, I have input fields:

```
<form>
    <input placeholder="John" ng-model="mainCtrl.manualEntry.firstName"/>
    <input placeholder="Smith" ng-model="mainCtrl.manualEntry.lastName"/>
</form>

<button type="submit"
        ng-disabled="mainCtrl.disableForm()"
        title="Submit">Submit
</button>
```

---

I thought that `$scope` automatically updated the model for use in the controller. I thought using `dot notation` in the DOM would push these values to the array.

When I update these values, the `submit` button on the form remains disabled (i.e. disableForm() returns true).

How can I push these values to `self.manualEntry` when they change or are updated on the DOM?

Comment: First, the name of the controller should not appear in your ng-model tag. So it should be : ng-model="manualEntry.firstName". Same in your ng-disabled.
And then, Why do not use "$scope.manualEntry" just like that ? Because manualEntry.firstName and manualEntry.lastName means you have an object like $scope.manualEntry{firstName : '', lastName: ''}

Comment: Why are you using array instead of object?

Comment: @M.Be OP is using controller instead of scope. Perfectly valid and even recommended option.

Comment: Button should be inside the <form> tags. Form tag should (ideally) have novalidate on it. manualEntry as you have declared it won't work. Models are objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am making a large assumption on what you want but it seems regular form validation is the way to go for this. Demo at http://plnkr.co/edit/Nzmk3R8eU0fmbBZRrTBa?p=info.

Controller Code

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  // set an empty array
  var self = this;
  self.manualEntry = {};

  //Let HTML5 handle the form validation itself
  self.printInfo = function() {
    console.log(self.manualEntry);
  };
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="mainCtrl.printInfo()">
    <input placeholder="John" ng-model="mainCtrl.manualEntry.firstName" ng-required="true" />
    <input placeholder="Smith" ng-model="mainCtrl.manualEntry.lastName" ng-required="true" />

    <button type="submit" title="Submit">Submit
    </button>
  </form>
</body>
```